# Amazon SES SPF Setup - when using -all how do you setup a record for your servers IP

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, spf

I have been reading this page on setting up SPF for my domain sending email through Amazon SES to my subscribers.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/spf.html

I have added the SPF as suggested :

> "spf2.0/pra include:amazonses.com -all"

Afterwards it notes the following:

> If you use "-all" as shown in the example above, ISPs may block email from IP addresses that are not listed in your Sender ID record. You therefore must add a record for every IP address that you send email from. As a debugging aid, you can use "~all" instead. When you use "~all", ISPs will typically accept email from IP addresses that are not listed. However, they may flag it. To maximize deliverability, use "-all" and add a record for each IP address.

All of my email is sent from my server for which I know the IP address. As such I want to setup a record for my servers IP - I am simply a little confused as to what I need to be using. Is it simply another record as follows:

> "spf2.0/pra include:127.0.0.1 -all"

where 127.0.0.1 is replaced with my servers IP?

I have had a look at the openspf website with little success - a basic idea of what the correct record is would be great.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

- spf2.0/pra is SenderID syntax. While similar in name to SPF proper, they are different protocols. For an explanation of the differences and the controversy surrounding SPF vs. SenderID, check [here](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_vs_Sender_ID).
- for the SPF record syntax, check [here](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax). The most simple way to add your server to the record is as follows: `"v=spf1 ip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx include:amazonses.com -all"`, where xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx should be replaced by your server's IP. Another option, if the A or MX record for your domain points to your mailserver's IP is: `"v=spf1 a include:amazonses.com -all"` or `"v=spf1 mx include:amazonses.com -all"`. It's also allowed to add them all at the same time.